# This is Day 1 of learning React. I was trying to create a new react app but i am getting these errors in vs code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
PS D:\reacttut> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in D:\reacttut\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC 
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/scheduler: 11056:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed 
or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\REACT\react_new\_logs\2022-04-27T09_03_11_917Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\reacttut
Done.
```

Comment: check your node version, must be greater or equal to 14. Or install the [latest](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: According to react documentation be sure that:  Node >= 14.0.0 and npm >= 5.6